# Vuetify vertical divider with text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am looking to add a vertical divider using vuetify along with text in between. I found this [link](https://codepen.io/Mert75/pen/YzqwdPo) which is adding a horizontal divider with text. I tried modifying the code as `<v-row align="center"> <v-divider vertical></v-divider>yeah<v-divider vertical></v-divider> </v-row>` but could not get the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.
Desired result

```
    |
   yeah
    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can do it** like this:

```
<v-row wrap no-gutters>
    <v-col cols="12" class="text-center">
        <v-divider vertical />
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" class="text-center"> some </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" class="text-center">
        <v-divider vertical />
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        <v-divider vertical class="mx-4"></v-divider>yeah<v-divider vertical class="mx-4"></v-divider>
```

Since you didn't have margins set, the divider was right up against the text, making it hard to see.

Comment: You can try it in the codepen link I have added. It's not the desired result